# Set left-handed mouse and right-handed touchpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 22.04, wayland

I upgraded to 22.04, [which uses](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406862/what-is-xwayland-what-if-i-remove-it-from-ubuntu-22-04) Wayland instead of X as the display manager. Similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376994/make-mouse-left-handed-and-touchpad-right-handed), I want to set my USB mouse to left-handed, while keeping my laptop touchpad right-handed. However, the solution there uses `xinput`, which is apparently incompatible with Wayland.

Is there a solution that works for 22.04 with Wayland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is verified to work with Wayland

1. Install input-remapper `$ sudo apt-get install input-remapper`
2. Run it and select the mouse.
3. Map Button Right to BTN_LEFT:[image]
4. Map Button Left to BTN_RIGHT:[image]
5. Click "Apply" button. This will not affect the touchpad.

After you applied the change (input-remapper-gtk), the settings may be lost in a while. I have no idea how to make the change effective automatically when the computer started.